# Translate a SQL request to Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, translate, query-builder

I have a complicate request that I hope translate with Eloquent ORM or with Query Builder for a Laravel Website, but I can't do this, particularly because of INNER JOIN and the double name on FROM

This is my SQL request

```
SELECT u.name,
       u.photo,
       m.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN messages m ON u.id = m.useridsend
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT useridsend,
    MAX(created_at) AS created_at
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY useridsend
) r ON m.useridsend = r.useridsend
AND m.created_at = r.created_at
WHERE m.useridreceive=2
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC;
```

Comment: [Raw Expressions](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions) might help you out

Comment: Thanks, it can help me, but I really want know if it's possible  to translate this request SQL without pure SQL but just with query builder

Comment: Give me a few minutes. Writing an answer to this using your SQL code in Eloquent format

Comment: Please could you provide more code as to your Model set up? Also, in this instance using short table names such as 'u' and 'm' can become very confusing. There isn't really any need to do this. Make it easy for yourself, use descriptive names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at making your query into Eloquent syntax using [Raw Expressions](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions). Bear in mind this may not be correct as I haven't tested it, and your use of shorthand makes it awkward to build. You need a lot of raw queries in your code, and I assume the `AND` statement was for the inner join:

```
DB::selectRaw("u.name, u.photo, m.* from users u")
->joinRaw("messages m ON u.id = m.useridsend")
->joinRaw("(SELECT useridsend, 
            MAX(created_at) AS created_at
            FROM messages
            GROUP BY useridsend) 
           r ON m.useridsend = r.useridsend
           AND m.created_at = r.created_at")
->whereRaw("m.useridreceive=2")
->orderBy('m.created_at', 'DESC')
->get();
```

Like I said, it might not be 100% correct, but I hope you get the idea of how to use `raw` queries. Using fewer shorthand names for tables might also make it easier to use standard Eloquent code.

EDIT

Also, could this not be simplified by taking advantage of Models? It looks like you're trying to get all messages sent to a user. With a User model defined as well as a Message model, you could take advantage of some [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) techniques and use something like

```
User::where('id', '=', '2')->with('messages')->get();
```

Comment: I tried to modify her with fewer shorthand so I don't use the "u" and the "m" but "users" dans "messages" but Laravel answers "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::joinRaw()"

Comment: I tried to retrieve the more recent message receive by users for one user. And with lot of research and subjects post, the only answer that I found and who work it this request.

Comment: I find the solution, it's little différent of you